# Chances of getting admitted while applying to a German PhD program without a master's degree from Germany?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, germany

I am a molecular biology graduate with an expected master's degree in biology. Both of these degrees are from prestigious universities in my home country, however none of which are in EU. Considering I had relevant job and research experiences here and also some internships in Germany, what are the chances that I get admitted to a PhD program in Germany (considering that I have good proposal and a command on German language)?

Comment: Two downvotes without any comments or suggestions what about the question should be improved?

Comment: @OP: There are typically (with few exceptions, though) no "PhD programs" in Germany. Applications to PhDs usually to go directly to potential advisors (there are a number of questions and answers about this topic on this site; it might be helpful if you search for them).

Comment: Oh, one more thing (though this does not directly answer the question): For foreign students who would like to do their PhD in Germany, scholarships by the [DAAD](https://www.daad.de/en/) (= "Deutscher Akademischer Austauschdienst", in English "German Academic Exchange Service") can sometimes be a good source of funding.

Comment: Thank you Jochen! Yes I know that they are different than that in English-speaking countries and mostly individual, I just wanted my question to be a little more understandable, I thought people would get what I mean. My question is actually if the approval by the potential is enough (considering that I already hold an MSc).

Comment: Thank you also for the DAAD suggestion. And yes, I also don't the reason for downvotes, if it is duplicate or anything I would prefer a comment and a redirection to a similar question.

Comment: What does *expected* Master's degree mean? You don't have it yet but will when starting as PhD student? In that case: there would be nothing very special in that respect wrt what is usual in Gemany.

Comment: @cbeleites Yes, I am currently enrolled and hopefully finish it succesfully. My problem is that I have doubts that I would have a harder admission since my master's isn't from Germany.

Comment: Note that the terms "PhD program" and "admission" are actually incorrect/misleading when talking about a PhD in Germany - being understandable is good, but one should not sacrifice correctness for that.

Comment: I understand, I'll keep that in mind, thank you. What terms one should use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You best source of information will be the professor in whose group you plan to apply. Since I'd anyways recommend to get in contact with them beforehand since that's the usual way this isn't something out of the ordinary.

I don't expect a Master's that is not completely recognized will hamper your application much: you'd be one among many including also PhD students with Bachelor's from Bachelor -> PhD countries and PhD students with Master's from Fachhochschule or from other fields.
My experience is that in these cases the university may ask you to take some exams that are in close relation to the PhD project to show your proficiency with the field of your thesis.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. My mind has been busy with this for quite a while.

Comment: How do you know OP's Master's degree would not be (completely) recognized? The likelihood of it getting recognized is quite good.

Comment: Actually it is H+ on Anabin, and is a relatively well known state university. Legally, there shouldn't be a problem. My doubts arise from the fact that it's not from an EU country, if that will give the supervisors a doubt about its educational quality.

Comment: @Roland: I don't know. What But even if it isn't, I don't think that will hamper the application since there are established procedures to deal with this. I'll clarify the answer.